# SendKeys.Send : Access is denied

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I have an Application which uses SendKeys.Send function to `send CTRL+C and CTRL+V Keys.` My operating system is `Windows Server 2012 R2`. It sends the keys at first with no problem but then it says Access is Denied. Why ?

I have tried to use these two methods,

```
SendKeys.Send()
```

and

```
My.Computer.Keyboard.SendKeys()
```

Both the functions giving the same Error at certain point.

Why it's not allowing me to send keys ?

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied
   at System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendInput(Byte[] oldKeyboardState, Queue previousEvents)
   at System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send(String keys, Control control, Boolean wait)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Keyboard.SendKeys(String keys)
   at WhatsApp_API_Sender.Form1.timercron_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: its hard to troubleshoot it without your source code. its possible you need to use System.Threading.Thread.Sleep() if SendKeys.Send() are executing multiple times line after line.

Comment: Code is simple. Just get text from the website URL. Copy to clipboard and paste it in the notepad. SendKeys.Send("^{v}") SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")

Comment: Yes. I have also put the Thread.Sleep(1). I get this error on the windows server only. When I run on windows 10 I don't get this error. Why ?

Comment: Is this running in background from timer? Also does it run when you lock the pc?

Comment: what i could think about is that after X time your your NT user is disconnecting.

Comment: Yes. It's running background from timer. No I didn't lock my pc. I'm using Google cloud VM instance of Win server 2012 R2.

Comment: @jonathana : I'm connected via RDP. and continuously monitoring it.

Comment: So you execute two `SendKeys` after each other. What happens if you make them both `SendKeys.SendWait()`?

Comment: Where should I keep SendKeys.SendWait() ? @VisualVincent

Comment: Just replace the Send with SendWait

Comment: Same problem. :/ What is the alternative to this ? After Adding Thread.sleep. still same error. SendKeys.SendWait("text")
                Thread.Sleep(2)

                'Hit Enter to get into Search Bar
                SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}")
                Thread.Sleep(2)